PyQGIS - How to iterate through each point in a raster layer to create a colour map
I'm working on a PyQGIS plugin where I need to iterate through every coordinate in a raster layer to apply a custom rating function. The aim is to create a new raster layer where each pixel is colored based on the result of this rating function.
This custom rating function (scorePoint) is working fine, but I've been struggling to perfect a way to iterate through points on the raster. Any ideas? This is what I'm using currently:
maxRasterHeight and maxRasterWidth are the dimensions of the main raster the analysis is done upon. Same for mainRasterExtent.
#Create empty array for each cell in the raster
rasterArray = np.zeros((maxRasterHeight, maxRasterWidth), dtype=np.int32)

cellWidth = 1
cellHeight = 1

for col in range(0, maxRasterWidth+cellWidth, cellWidth): #Iterate thru each column
    for row in range(0, maxRasterHeight+cellHeight, cellHeight): #Iterate thru each cell/row
        #Convert the indices to coordinates
        x = mainRasterExtent.xMinimum() + col
        y = mainRasterExtent.yMinimum() + row
                
        point = QgsPointXY(x, y)

        score = self.scorePoint(point)
                                
        rasterArray[row, col] = score

#Set up GDAL to create new raster
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
geoTransform = [mainRasterExtent.xMinimum(), cellWidth, 0, mainRasterExtent.yMinimum(), 0, cellHeight]
newRaster = driver.Create(path, xsize=maxRasterWidth, ysize=maxRasterHeight, bands=1, eType=gdal.GDT_Byte)

#Write the array to the raster
rasterToCreate.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)
rasterToCreate.SetGeoTransform(geoTransform)
rasterToCreate.SetProjection(self.mainRaster.crs().authid())

rasterToCreate = None

Is there a better way I could be doing this? It's giving quite a few issues, I can't increase the cell size without causing issues, and the code seems to take very long to iterate through.

What is scorePoint doing? It might be faster if it took the pixel value rather than doing a lookup with the point.

It scores based on proximity to a few broadcast points that are on the terrain, so I think it would need to be the point value as this is what is used to determine this proximity. Basically scorePoint rates the signal quality of each point, from these broadcasters on the terrain. It then would return a number for the colour rating of the point passed to it.

Iterating through a large multi-dimensional array is always going to be expensive. It's probably going to come down to the scorePoint function, and whether you can somehow optimise it so it can operate on an array at a time. It sounds like that's unlikely but hard to know without seeing it.

I hadn't thought about using the function on whole arrays at a time. I'll look into that next. Thank you!
